# GCP VPC Service Control with Private Service Connect

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-vpc, vpc-endpoint

I am planning to implement VPC Service Control perimeter on my GCP project, allowing access to Google APIs. Based on documentation, I need to set up DNS records to `restricted.googleapis.com` with specific IP range (`199.36.153.4, 199.36.153.5, 199.36.153.6, 199.36.153.7`).
To my understanding, this traffic does not reach internet and stays in Google's network.

My question is - how about using VPC Service Control together with Private Service Connect? I was thinking of creating an endpoint for Google services (type `VPC-SC`) and then have `*.googleapis.com` and even `restricted.googleapis.com` DNS records pointing to the private IP of that endpoint within my VPC.

I am just wondering if that makes sense and if it brings any benefit compared to just using DNS records and routing to route traffic toward `restricted.googleapis.com`?

Thank you and best regards,
Bostjan